# Is there a word for feeling like a memory is manufactured?

Tags: single-word-requests

Often in normal conversations I have moments where I say "Oh I remember that!" and then think to myself, do I really remember or have I manufactured that memory based on current conversation?

I'm a developer, and this comes out a lot in my daily work, I think because we see so many interrelated concepts that it's easy to convince ourselves we heard of XYZ class.

I could give at least one specific, but I don't think it relevant to this site to talk about code.

Comment: There's no name for it that I know, but you should read Beth Loftus's work on eyewitness memory. Manufacturing memories on the fly is not only real but normal; most experiential memories are manufactured.

Comment: [Déjà vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu), maybe?

Comment: What did they use in Inception?

Comment: This belongs on [english.se].

Comment: Misremembrance?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [False Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory)

Comment: In _Blade Runner_, manufactured memories (courtesy of the Tyrell Corporation) are called _implants_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "[confabulated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confabulate)."

Comment: I was pleased but not surprised to see that there is a word for that common experience.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this and got to use it in an email today already!